# Docker compose yml static IP addressing

Tags: docker-compose, docker-network

I have such docker-compose.yml (not a full list here):

```
version: '2'

services:

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - php
    volumes_from:
      - app
    networks:
      app_subnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.3

  php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes_from:
      - app
    networks:
      app_subnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.4

    networks:
      app_subnet:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 172.16.1.0/24
          gateway: 172.16.1.1
```

After `docker-compose up` I got such an error:

> User specified IP address is supported only when connecting to
>   networks with user configured subnets

So I'm creating subnet with `docker network create --gateway 172.16.1.1 --subnet 172.16.1.0/24 app_subnet`

But this doesn't solve the problem because docker-compose creates the subnet with name dev_app_subnet on the fly. And my subnet is not used - I'm getting the same error. 
The main purpose of doing this is to assign static IP for nginx service - open my project web url from etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found the solution.

When pointing to the network, we should use flag "external" telling compose that network is already created and should be taken outside (otherwise it will be created on the fly with project prefix):

```yaml
networks:
  app_subnet:
    external: true
```

So, after that docker-compose will attach containers to existing `app_subnet`
Before that the subnet must be created:

```bash
docker network create --gateway 172.16.1.1 --subnet 172.16.1.0/24 app_subnet
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case is i first run `docker-compose up` failed, but the network already created, can see using `docker network ls`.

In this case, just `docker-compose down`, fix the yml, rerun `docker-compose up` is fine

Comment: Worked for me too since the network was created with the wrong configuration when running `docker-compose up` for the first time. So there was no need for configuring external network.

Answer (score 7):

It is probable that from previous run of the script the network interface was already created but without the subnet parameter.

For fixing it run

```
docker network ls -a
```

and remove the network that is blocking the creation of the service

```
docker network rm <network interface id>
```

Comment: As of writing the command `docker network ls` does not support the option `-a`. Apart from this, this answer worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To be specific if you're using docker stack deploy to deploy a swarm cluster. And you need to specify the scope of the subnet as 'swarm':

> docker network create --gateway 172.16.1.1 --subnet 172.16.1.0/24
>   --scope swarm app_subnet

in the docker-compose.yml, you need to specify the external network as:

> networks:   default:
>       external:
>         name: etl_subnet

Use it as default.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the **Qiushi's** answer, you can use the `docker-compose 3.9` version to specify the external network as below.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
networks:
  network1:
    external: true
    name: etl_subnet
```

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network-configuration-reference